# PHP multidimentional Array - Extract Cildren / Parents

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to parse an multidimentional array that goes like this:
For example I'd like to extract all the names of the children for *NAME => Ma,* and all their children again.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 35
        [Name] => Ma
        [Note] => 
        [parent_id] => 0
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 55
                        [Name] => OS
                        [Note] => 
                        [parent_id] => 35
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ID] => 416
                                        [Name] => fs
                                        [Note] => 
                                        [parent_id] => 55
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ID] => 921
                                        [Name] => fd
                                        [Note] => 
                                        [parent_id] => 55
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [2] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ID] => 980
                                        [Name] => FP
                                        [Note] => 
                                        [parent_id] => 55
                                        [DomainID] => 1
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                    )

                            )
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 59
                        [Name] => PC
                        [Note] => 
                        [parent_id] => 35
                        [children] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [ID] => 60
                                        [Name] => IT
                                        [Note] => 
                                        [parent_id] => 59
                                        [children] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )
```

The array keeps going like this. More parents, more children.... 
The only data I'm trying to extract is the Name, but I need to get them in such a way that I know what parent they belong to.

```
foreach($outArray as $row => $innerArray){
foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
echo $value . "<br/>";
```

One way I tried to extract the data but that does not get any children.

Comment: How are you trying exactly, what does your code look like and how does it not do what you need it to do?

Comment: Post your code please and we can help you.

Comment: @jeroen I've tried running foreach loops like this:
foreach($outArray as $row => $innerArray){
foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
echo $value . "<br/>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `array_walk_recursive` in php that handles this. You can use that. I have prepared a sample code for you. Please see below:

```
$results = array();

array_walk_recursive($array, function ($item, $key) use (&$results){
    if ($key == 'Name') {
        $results[] = $item;
    }
});

var_dump($results);
```

The above code will output the values of all the "Name" keys in your array.

Please let me know if this is what you were expecting. You can find more on `array_walk_recursive` [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great, but how can I call only the children of [Name] => Ma for example?

Comment: I have provided you a baseline. Please feel free to modify the code.